# SQL Issue. Need to check data type for a trigger before insert

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm creating a before insert and before update trigger that checks for the data type. For example, I have a `ytd_sales` field which is a `NUMBER`. I want to make a trigger that prints an error message if someone tries inserting say a varchar here.
I tried doing the likes of...

```
IF :new.ytd_sales != NUMBER THEN
//print the message
```

However this gives compilation errors. Any insight?

Here's some code for reference.

```
SHOW ERRORS;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER before_insert_book
BEFORE INSERT ON book
        FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
        IF :new.ISBN is NULL THEN
                raise_application_error(-20000, 'ISBN is null, insert was not accepted. Please revise your insert statement');
        END IF;
        IF :new.title is NULL THEN
                raise_application_error(-20000, 'TITLE is null, insert was not accepted. Please revise your insert statement');
        END IF;
        /*
        IF :new.isbn != VARCHAR2 THEN
                raise_application_error(-20001, 'isbn is of wrong type, please correct.');
        END IF;

        IF :new.title != VARCHAR2 THEN
                raise_application_error(-20001, 'title is of wrong type, please correct.');
        END IF;

        IF :new.pub_id != VARCHAR2 THEN
                raise_application_error(-20001, 'pub id is of wrong type, please correct.');
        END IF;

        IF :new.price != NUMBER THEN
                raise_application_error(-20001, 'number is of wrong type, pleace correct.');
        END IF;

        IF :new.advance != NUMBER THEN
                raise_application_error(-20001, 'advance is of wrong type, please correct.');
        END IF;

        IF :new.ytd_sales != NUMBER THEN
                raise_application_error(-20001, 'ytd sales is of wrong type, please correct.');
        END IF;

        IF :new.pubdate is not DATE THEN
                raise_application_error(-20001, 'pubdate is of wrong type, please correct.');
        END IF;
        */

END;
/
```

Comment: Create a stored procedure to insert rows and use parameters of appropriate data types.

Comment: If you try to insert anything into a number field that Oracle can't translate to a number - it will raise the error for you. And any data type can be cast to a varchar, so those checks aren't helpfull either. the fact is that if Oracle hasn't managed to cast the input into the correct datatype then you won't get into the trigger to test the values in the :NEW fields. By definition they must have been castable in order to have been stored into the field datatype. Now - If you have specific formats in mind, then that is another issue entirely.

Comment: I am aware that it raises the error for me. But this is the assignment we have been given... It is to give us some practice with triggers. We also had to do null checks but I have that covered.

Comment: Oracle will check the data type before your trigger would be fired. So if the values provided don't match the data type, your trigger will never have the chance to do this validation again

Comment: But it is a before insert or before update trigger. Why would the trigger not get hit before the error message is created?

Comment: How can a varchar exist in a :NEW.price field if :NEW.price is a number? It can't. Oracle has already tried to fill the values before executing the trigger. If it couldn't, it raised the error already.

Comment: Whoever gave you this assignment, you can tell them that the SO community thinks it's a stupid assignment because it provides zero functional value.  If you want practice with triggers, try inserting audit records in an audit table to store the old value and new value when something changes in the target table.

Comment: And, as a final comment - put constraints like NOT NULL on the table whenever possible - not in a trigger. You are doing a context switch to execute code unnecessarily (performance hit - Oracles' kernel can do those tests WAY faster), and triggers can be disabled which would shoot your data integrity to hell if any data was being modified while the trigger was turned off. Jim's assessment is bang on. Its a stupid assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, Oracle will take care of the case of trying to shoehorn a varchar into a number for you. But you could, for example, verify that a varchar isn't entirely numeric by trying to cast it to a number and raising an error if you succeed. To do this you use a nested BEGIN..EXCEPTION..END block.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER before_insert_book
BEFORE INSERT ON book
        FOR EACH ROW
   nmbr_chk number;
BEGIN
        IF :new.ISBN is NULL THEN
                raise_application_error(-20000, 'ISBN is null, insert was not accepted. Please revise your insert statement');
        END IF;
        IF :new.title is NULL THEN
                raise_application_error(-20000, 'TITLE is null, insert was not accepted. Please revise your insert statement');
        END IF;

        BEGIN
              nmbr_chk  := to_number(:new.isbn);
              -- if we got here we succeeded and ISBN is numeric, so fail
              raise_application_error(-20001, 'isbn is of wrong type, please correct.');
         EXCEPTION
             WHEN value_error 
             THEN 
                  -- great, its not a number so continue.
                  NULL;
         END;
END;
/
```

Comment: this looks promising, trying it out now.

Comment: Note that I only specifically handle the VALUE_ERROR exception, otherwise you would trap and then ignore the -20001 that we raised inside the block. Something to be careful about if you ever feel tempted to take shortcuts like WHEN OTHERS...

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without a trigger.  Triggers are very powerful but should only be used if you cannot do the job a simpler way.

Modify your table to have a constraint that all values that have to have a value have a NOT NULL constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD CONSTRAINT your_constraint_name_here CHECK(mynumber IS NOT NULL) ;
```

Oracle will do your type checking for you. You do not need to check if they are putting a string into a number.  This will throw an exception.  That you can catch in the application that is driving this.

A stored procedure to apply your business logic is always a good idea as it puts the logic in one place.

- easier maintenance
- reusability

Comment: I am aware it can be done with constraints. But this is an assignment we were given. I need to know how to do it with a trigger BEFORE insert or update.